# It is posible to get a list of commits when doing force push?

Tags: git, github

I am using [Zola](https://www.getzola.org/) and after building, I am publishing the static site to a git repository with something like this:

```bash
cd public
git init
git add -A
git commit -m "Deploy site"
git push --force git@github.com:<user>/<user>.github.io.git main
```

`zola build` creates a new `public` dir and I need to do `git init` to initialize the git repository and be available to publish into the repo `<user>.github.io.git` in where I see only the static content as expected, but how could I see the previous commits?

I already tried `git reflog` and always only see the last pushed commit, is there a way to see the history of all commits?

The repo is hosted in GitHub but also there I don't see any list of commits, wondering if there is a way to `push --force` but preserve the commits just as an identifier of what has been deployed.

I am aware that with `--force`  the commit history on the remote will be forcefully overwritten with the local history, and If I would like history just need to push without `--force`, but it is ok for this use case since I am only using git for hosting static content in this repo and by using `--force` it helps prevent also increasing it in size.

The reasons I would like to see the commits, if possible, is to match what has been deployed or it is served via web, when using services like Cloudflare pages, in were they publish contents of a repo or branch after something has been added, currently, I can only see last commit, but if wanted to see previous commits since I am using `--force` I don't have them, I indeed can reproduce the output of that commit by running again `zola build` on the parent git repo (using the desired version/tag/checksum) but I would like to simplify this by relating the commits that trigger the deploy (the ones I publish with the --force) so that I instead having to build based on dates, I could just match the checksums, any ideas, alternatives suggestions?

Comment: the script you show starts with `git init`. Do you run any other action that would get rid of your local repo ?

Comment: after doing a `zola build` the `public`  is not a repo so I need to run `git init` to initialize it and then push its contents

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your question: you build your site with something like `zola build`, and then in folder `public` you create git repository and push it to github with `--force`.

If my understanding is correct, then every time at build your previous repository is removed (because zola deletes and recreates folder `public`), then recreated, and this newly recreated repo pushed to github, where it rewrites previous version.

It is misuse of git (and github i suppose). If you want history of your built states:

1. Create permanent local repo outside of your project.
2. After build step sync `public` folder of your project with repo (ignoring folder `.git` in said repo)
3. Commit changes to repo
4. Push this repo to github (without `--force`)